# fadein +left animate jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

original :

```
         $('#'+d[i].id).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing'); 

    $('#'+d[i].id).('opacity', 0).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing',{'opacity': 1}, 1000);
```

how do i fade in and slide the graphics...from the left (the sliding of the grpahics is happening but not fading in....

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `.css` in your code?

You currently have:

```
$('#'+d[i].id).('opacity', 0).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing',{'opacity': 1}, 1000);
```

Try this:

```
$('#'+d[i].id).css('opacity', 0).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing',{'opacity': 1}, 1000);
```

As for both of them at the same time:

```
$('#'+d[i].id).css('opacity', 0).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000, opacity: 1},1000,'swing');
```

Comment: for all intents and purpose this works although the effect is slightly misleading because the outgoign image and the incomming image  both fade in for the outgoing image :  opcaity 1 - opacity 0 - opacity 1 and incomming image opacity 0 - opacity -1 ...thanks any ways...

Comment: @andy Yeah I figured the final event wouldn't quite be what you're after, but I'm sure you'll know how to finalize that to your desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate multiple properties at once:

```
.animate({left:(i-pos)*1000,opacity:1}, 1000, 'swing')
```